# Enforce JOIN instead of Subquey when using "__in" filter in Django ORM

Tags: django, join, orm, database-optimization

**Task:** I want to get all invoices where the project title matches a given string. The `Invoice` has a foreign key to `Project`.

**The problem:** I want to use a function for doing the project search so I can recycle and encapsulate this use-caes. To make this happen I have to use the `__in` operator instead of `project__title__icontains=my_str`. This will lead to an inefficient subquery. The later will create an efficient JOIN.

**Code examples**

I have two custom queryset methods. One lives in `Project`:

```py
def search_title(self, title: str):
    """
    Searches for projects having the given title or at least parts of it.
    """
    return self.filter(title__icontains=title)
```

The second one lives in `Invoice`:

```py
def search_project_title(self, project_title: str):
    return self.filter(project__in=Project.objects.search_title(project_title))
```

**Any ideas how I can tell the Django ORM that I prefer JOINs over Subqueries?**

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you filter with:

```
def search_project_title(self, project_title: str):
    return self.filter(project__title__icontains=project_title)
```

Comment: Thx for the input but as I said I want to use the function and NOT use the field of the fk-related model directly.